# WFST-T update attributes after creating object

Tags: attributes, openlayers

I`m quite new to openlayers and trying to use wfs-t to let users add geometries to a map (using geoserver and a postgis-db in the background). This works quite well however I would like the users to add/edit some metadata of the geometries as well.
Is there any more or less easy to understand example/tutorial out there?